# Are automotive engineering question on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I wanted to ask "is there a technical reason why an electric vehicle could not be made with a manual transmission (stick-shift)?" - would this question be on-topic?

This site feels like the closest to an appropriate venue for this question, but the "what topics can I ask about here?" section implies this site is more to ask about automotive-related *repairs*. The next closest matching stack exchange that I could think of might have been engineering, but its "what topics can I ask about here?"  section left me feeling it was a less appropriate venue.

If here's not the right venue for the noted question, any suggestions where else in the Stack Exchange community would be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

1. There is a tag called: [engine-theory](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engine-theory) ... it is all about (or should be) theoretical stuff. As of this answer, there are 326 questions against it, so I'd say it's on topic.
2. [Your question has already been asked.](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/6179/4152)